# How do you properly allow two devices on separate subnets to communicate (PFSense)?

Tags: networking, routing, firewall, subnet, pfsense

I'm trying to figure out how to get 192.168.0.22 to properly ping/be able to transfer files with 192.168.77.10. Firstly, is this a dumb setup? I'm mainly using it right now just for educational purposes, such as this question I'm asking now.

I am able to ping the firewall's LAN address 192.168.77.254 from 192.168.0.22 and when I traceroute from 0.22 to 77.10 I get it to show 192.168.0.254 but then it gets lost from there.

I've tried setting up liberal allow rules on both LAN and WAN interfaces and a 1:1 NAT as well with no luck. Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.[image: enter code here]

UPDATE (adding static route image on 192.168.0.1 router and traceroute from 192.168.0.22 to 192.168.77.10 firewall logs)

[image]
[image]

Comment: From your ping/traceroute results, it sounds like the main router (192.168.0.1) already has the correct routes set up, right? I would first suggest running `tcpdump ...` on the pfSense to check whether packets aren't going through in one direction or whether they're getting stuck in the other.

Comment: Why are you using a 1:1 NAT on the pfSense? Plain routing would be so much simpler. 1:1 NAT just complicates matters.

Comment: I'm guessing the usage of NAT came from pfSense's "like a home router" default configuration (with its insistence on calling the first two interfaces 'WAN' and 'LAN' whether it makes sense or not...)

Comment: Have you tried *disabling* the IP masquerade ("many-to-one" NAT) that is most likely set up at the pfSense WAN for its LAN subnet?

Comment: The only original NAT rules were Auto created rule for ISAKMP (127.0.0.0/8 ::1/128 192.168.77.0/24)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you will need to disable outbound NAT, otherwise the replies from `backup drives` won't be recognized as replies by `MediaServer` as their source IP address will become `192.168.0.254`, which differs from the *original* traffics' *destination* address `192.168.77.10` (because destination NAT a.k.a. port forwarding was not involved). Both `manual` and `disable` should work:

[image]

But apart from that, you will also need to configure the firewall for a bit. You can either simply disable the firewall entirely:

[image]

which would also disable outbound NAT (so the first step can be skipped if you opt for this);

Or, you can add a WAN firewall rule. For example:

[image]

Note that because the WAN side subnet in your case is a private one. You must *additionally* disable "Block private networks" if you chose to add an exception/pass rule only:

[image]

For the record, *ideally speaking* it would be best to have the route `192.168.77.0/24 via 192.168.0.254` configured on the `192.168.0.0/24` hosts, so that the communication in concern will be *symmetric* and not involving `Router` at all. (Well, I mean the *router part* of `Router`; certainly the *switch part* of it is always involved.) Other than configuring that manually on every host, *replacing* the DHCP server on `Router` with a more customizable one that allows you to configure additional route(s) to push is another option.

For example, you can configure `pfSense` to host a WAN-side DHCP server (I *assume* it is capable of what I just mentioned). But certainly the process to set that up is most likely troublesome.

P.S. The test / showcase was done with OPNsense here but I don't suppose it differs a lot from pfSense. The bottom line is, the ideas apply anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your media-server will dumbly forward any traffic outside 192.168.0.0/24 to its default gateway (which is 192.168.0.1) and trust that gateway to forward it any further.

Do you have a static route setup on 192.168.0.1 to tell it that 192.168.77.0/24 is reachable via gateway 192.168.0.254 ?

Please bear in mind that even though 192.168.0.1 can directly see 192.168.0.254 it will have no idea what is BEHIND that pfSense node. The static route will give it that information.

If you can't add a route to 192.168.0.1 itself you will need to setup that route on each device that needs to reach 192.168.77.0/24 (like the mediaserver).

Comment: I did try adding that static route to my 192.168.0.1 (see image I added to main post). It looks like with the static route the PFsense firewall is still blocking requests when I run traceroute (image added for those as well). I added a liberal policy to allow all trafic into the WAN and LAN interfaces for the 192.168.0.22 IP and now I see the firewall appears to be blocking 192.168.0.1 so I'm going to see if allowing the router in will work.. is it a bad idea to allow all traffic from 192.168.0.1 though since it's the main point of contact from the outside after my modem? –

Comment: @NickGreen You can just allow the whole192.168.0.0/24 subnet (as source) on the firewall in pfSense. Traffic coming from the internet still lhas the original internet ip-address as source. And, unless you have setup port-forwarding (yourself or by UPnP) on the internet router there won't be any traffic arriving from the internet.

Comment: I take it my entire setup is not quite right in PFsense. I do have internet access without any sort of special WAN rules. My WAN_DHCP Gateway is showing at 192.168.0.1 on PFsense. My "WAN" interface is 192.168.0.254 and LAN interface is 192.168.77.254

Comment: @NickGreen That is the default setup in pfSense. It will standard configure the LAN side to be able to do Internet by NAT to the WAN interface (and it doesn't matter if WAN is directly connected to the Internet or there is an upstream router in between). And it will by default firewall WAN to LAN, but allow LAN to WAN. This makes sense for the most  common setup for a home or small business. But you can reconfigure it any way you want. Like others also mentioned in the comments: You probably don't want/need to do any NAT on the pfSense. Just plain routing between your 2 internal subnets.

Comment: I see. I did try disabling all NAT but think I may be missing some fundamental understanding of how things work in terms of how addresses are passed from the WAN interface (0.254) to the LAN interface (77.254) and then routed onwards to a host within the 192.168.77.0/24 network as traceroute requests to 77.10 seem to just bounce back and forth between 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.254